# SQLite support for PHP 4.2.3

Tags: php, sqlite

i wonder, is there a way to work with SQLite on PHP version 4.2.3 ?

if you say i must update my php version, no i can't simply update my PHP version.
the system already have database, but i can't change that database it's not my authority though i can view, edit, or do anything to that database.

so i think maybe it's easier if i use my own sqlite database and make my own function to deal with the sqlite database, but i don't know if it supported by PHP version 4.2.3

thanks, any suggestion would be a great lift.

Comment: If you are still using `PHP4`... please DON'T. **It's 2013!** If your employer forces you, QUIT... It can't get worse than PHP4. **PS**: I don't think you can. AFAIK, extensions are not backwards compatible... anyways, not THAT BACKWARDS compatible.

Comment: yeah i know, but this application already produce a lot of money :p and if i/we do a massive changing to the system it would take times.

Comment: You could write your own extenstion...

Answer (score 1):

For what I found, yes, is possible to have sqlite under php4.

- http://www.phpbuilder.com/columns/farell20040824.php3?page=1
- http://polarwebservices.com/hostingblog/?p=6
- http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/howto-install-sqlite-php4-servers-59201.html

And the source code of the sqlite extension is here: http://pecl.php.net/package/SQLite

Keep in mind is no longer supported, and is sqlite2 instead of sqlite3.

But if you are still using php4 on this year, I don't think you would really mind using an old sqlite, right? :P

By the way, IMHO, if that application makes you money, I think you should at least spend some time updating it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm faced with a similar situation being stuck with PHP4.  And I know where you're coming from (switching is much easier said than done specially if it's your own money you're spending).

But it's not the end of the world.  Like you I needed to integrate newer technologies to my app.  So what I did was instead to run 2 PHP versions along-side each other and created an API that I access via curl from PHP4.

That's the simplest approach I can think of.  Hope that helps. I feel you man hehehe...